# Criteria hibernate

Tags: hibernate

my code

```
session.createCriteria(Input.class);
      DateFormat format = 
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
      Date startDate = 
(Date)format.parse("2005-01-01 00:00:00");
      Date endDate = 
(Date)format.parse("2005-03-03 00:00:00");
      crit.add(Expression.between
("inputDate", new Date(startDate.getTime()),
 new Date(endDate.getTime())));
```

This code return a list, but there is no element present in it.
i think it doesn't match the condition.
Anybody help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your last statement:

```
crit.add(Expression.between("inputDate", startDate, endDate));
```

Comment: actually i didn't add .hbm.xml file in cfg file.
i got the solution.
thanks for your help.